# pty functionality for socket

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, pty, libreadline

I'm writing the linux daemon and I want to implement ability to configure its params via telnet. I have a cli interface code, written using gnu readline library with history and completers and I'd like to using that interface code for daemon.

I tried to redirect stdin/stdout to socket, redirected rl_instream/rl_outstream to socket, read/write to master/slave pty, but without success.

[similar question asked here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.os.linux.development.apps/WY9XcjKe3cY/discussion) without any answers.

Also read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500344/forkpty-socket), but I do not have child process.

My questions are:

1. How can I use pty functionality inside the single process?
2. Do I need to use master and slave pty if I have single process only?

Code example (with no operations on pty devices), expected result - readline works properly

```
char* readline_buff;

int main(void){
int mSock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP);
int socketfd, n, flag = 1;

int addrlen;
daemon(1,1);
setsockopt(mSock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &flag, sizeof(int));
struct sockaddr_in addr;
bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(5000);
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
bind(mSock, (const sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
listen(mSock,SOMAXCONN);
addrlen = sizeof(addrlen);
bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));

int m_pty = posix_openpt(O_RDWR);
grantpt(m_pty);
unlockpt(m_pty);
string m_ptsname = ptsname(m_pty);
int slave = open(m_ptsname.c_str(), O_RDWR);
//
socketfd = accept(mSock, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, (socklen_t*)&addrlen);
//
close(STDOUT_FILENO);
dup2(socketfd, STDOUT_FILENO);
close(STDIN_FILENO);
dup2(socketfd, STDIN_FILENO);
close(STDERR_FILENO);
dup2(socketfd, STDERR_FILENO);
//
 while(true){   
  readline_buff = readline("ME: ");
  add_history(readline_buff);
  free(readline_buff);
}
return 0;
}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: What PTY functionality does not work? Nothing? Are you talking about things like cursor keys similar things?

Comment: yes. i meant terminal key bindings. for history scroll in shell you can use up arrow key, but in my test app it prints:
    telnet localhost 5000
    Trying 127.0.0.1...
    Connected to localhost.
    Escape character is '^]'.
    ME: ^[[A
    ME: 
    ME: ^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A
    telnet>

Answer (score 1):

The telnet protocol is basically a line-based protocol, therefore it doesn't handle single key-presses or special codes easily. You can ask the connected telnet client to send every single key instead of lines, this is done by something called telnet negotiation.

To learn more about this, you should read the telnet RFC's, most importantly [RFC 854](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc854.html) and [RFC 855](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc855.html). For for disabling client-side editing you should also read [RFC 1116](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1116.html). Also check the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TELNET) to see a list of all telnet related RFC's.

In short you have to send a series of commands to the client to ask it to stop doing line-mode handling, and hope the client answers back that it will stop doing it. This is not simple stuff, quite the opposite actually. To implement a complete telnet state-machine can be though. Even then, you might not be able to properly use the readline library, as the keystrokes might not be recognized as proper up/down keys, and you might have to do some translations anyway. I actually recommend you to skip the normal stdin/stdout handling and PTY handling as well, and let the client handle editing, while you keep track of the history, either by using the functionality of an external library like readline, or by having an internal history queue.

Comment: thank you, i will read those RFCs. line editing is not problem i think, because i can read char by char from socket. for example while(errno != EGAIN){read(sock, &buff, 1);}. my question was - if there some way to use pty capabilities for socket in single process? i've found some examples for fork()'ed processes, but no one for single

Answer (score 0):

Pty is not needed. You need to configure new history keys for `readline` by adding the following lines to `/etc/inputrc` or `~/.inputrc` file:

```
"\e[A":history-search-backward
"\e[B":history-search-forward
```

Reason for that:

Usually terminal programs (read: telnet client) sends escape codes when user press Up or Down arrow key.

Escape codes are:

```
\33[A   - up arrow 
\33[B   - down arrow
```

Because your program prints: `^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A` , it does not regonise the escape sequence.
So you need to tell those escape sequences to the `readline`.

See [more information](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Readline)

Answer (score 0):

Readline provides a test file rlPtyTest.c that tests the readline via PTY. You can use it as a template for implementing sockets. https://github.com/alexmac/alcextra/blob/master/readline-6.2/examples/rlptytest.c